# Source Control Branching Strategy

Tags: sql-server, version-control

We are trying to determine the best source control branching strategy to use at work. We use a VSO frontend attached to a GIT backend. We have 4 database environments, DEV, QA, STAGE and PROD. At any given time we have many teams working on different features that often leapfrog each other, in addition to a lot of ongoing database cleanup work (adding Primary and Foreign Keys, setting columns to non nullable, etc)

My idea is to maintain four persistent branches, one for each database environment, that reflect their respective database environments. Any team working on a new feature will branch from Dev, and at the point the work is done merge back into the persistent DEV branch. When the work is ready to go to QA it will be merged to QA, at the point it is ready to move to STAGE it'll be merged to STAGE and so forth. Any non-breaking database updates not tied to a freature (like making columns non NULLABLE) can flow as change sets without needing a feature branch, but every potentially breaking change will need to work as a feature branch.

Has anyone used this strategy? Did it work?
Is there a better branching model you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one ended up answering I will use my own answer for an update. It appears we will end up using this branching strategy, more or less as I originally described. The main difference is that the PROD branch will be called master, and the feature branches will be branched from master rather than DEV.

This is because the master/PROD branch is considered more stable than DEV. The previous environment where I had branched from DEV successfully was a single release-train. Since features are expected to leapfrog each other here we can't do that.

Also, all development will need to be done in feature branches. This is due to a limitation of the VSO GIT plugin however, since the mechanism for linking GIT pushes to VSO tickets requires that work be done in feature branches.